# Convert array to associative

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I have following array using

```
print_r($data);
```

in php results to

```
$data=Array(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [name] => location
        [value] =>lko 
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [name] => street_number
        [value] => 425
    )
    )
```

Now I want to achieve the following format array ,How can i achieve followin using best complexity feasible

```
 Array(
[location]=>lko
[street_number]=>425)
```

I want the perfect complexity feasible solution,

Comment: RTFM ? http://php.net/json_decode   in particular the second option...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following

```
 foreach ($data as $val) {

    $ar[$val['name']]=$val['value'];
}
print_r($ar);
```

This will convert your array into the format you needed

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `serializeArray`. Use simple `serialize`:

```
var data = $("#form").serialize();
```

And on server side check with:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

It should have all values you need as key-value array.

Comment: Already tried so ,result to "location=lko&street_number=425"

Comment: Please edit your question and add relevant js code and php-part. `serialize` is a standard method and works fine.

Comment: @Lucky That is the format you want. If `.serialize` doesn't work for you, then you are doing something else wrong. You wouldn't put that value under another key, that is the data you pass into the ajax call.

Comment: @u_mulder I have edited and added the relevent js code

Comment: `data = JSON.stringify(data);` is useless when using `serialize` as it's already a string.